# c# and ios connect to facebook and get the profile information of the user

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, fbconnect, xamarin-studio

By the way I'am using c# for my ios app

Is there a way that I can connect my ios application to facebook so that I can get the profile information of the user from facebook and save it to my app.

Here's the scenario:

I have a login page, if they don't have an account they don't need to register they must simply use their facebook account to login - the user can use their facebook account to login.

How can I connect to facebook and get all the profile information of the user and display it in my ios app?.

Comment: Check the Facebook developers site for their SDK. Not sure how your use of C# will effect this though .. ? https://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers to get you started:

- Use Xamarin.Social: http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social/ You can install it from within the Component folder of your solution.
- Use bindings for the FB sdk: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook